# how can I check when was my db(my sql db) last restored successfully in aws

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

how can I check when was my db(my sql db) last restored successfully in aws?

I want to know how old db we are using , like for ec2 instances we can see the launch time of server, but how can i do that for db?

Comment: I'd try running this in the MySQL client: `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime'` but that shows the time since the last restart, not the last restore.

Comment: I want to know the last restore, the db gets restarted every day 